How to Sanitize Strings in Python for Safe LaTeX Compilation with pdflatex?
I'm using Python scripts to dynamically generate LaTeX PDFs based on a template that includes several user-provided fields such as:

username
error type
input description
error message

The content for some of these fields, specifically "username" and "input description," is provided by external users and may contain characters that cause the pdflatex compiler to fail. Currently, I am trying to replace or escape these characters, but I'm not sure if I'm covering all possible problematic inputs.
Here's what I have implemented so far in Python:
import re
def escape_latex_special_chars(input_string):
    latex_special_chars = {
        '&': r'\&',
        '%': r'\%',
        '$': r'\$',
        '#': r'\#',
        '_': r'\_',
        '{': r'\{',
        '}': r'\}',
        '~': r'\textasciitilde{}',
        '^': r'\textasciicircum{}',
        '\\': r'\textbackslash{}'
    }
    return re.sub(r'([&%$#_{}~^\\])', lambda match: latex_special_chars[match.group()], input_string)

Is there a safer approach or a Python package specifically designed to handle sanitization of any strings for LaTeX documents?
The sanitized strings should not only prevent compilation errors but also retain as much of the original formatting and readability as possible.
Any suggestions or recommendations for libraries and strategies to improve this sanitization process would be greatly appreciated.

Include the user provided text verbatim, like source code?

Verbatim indeed seems the most logical approach, this also preserves the formatting better regarding spaces and newlines.

Can you add an example of input with the expected LaTeXcode?

string/verbatim is the only sane approach here, as already suggested. since that seems to be the ideal formatting for your use case, the only real downside might be e.g. line breaking, but that's probably easier to deal with than escaping everything.

with verbatim you mean {here my crazy characters, foreign alphabets or umlauts} ? I guess that would still break if some monkey types a "{" or a "}" into the input fields. It would probably also be a good way to hack the software...

@mcExchange With verbatim we mean \begin{verbatim} monkey typing here \end{verbatim} (or lstlisting, minted etc.)
